# How to simplify a networkx graph?

Tags: python, networkx

I am looking to "simplify" a NetworkX Directed Graph on a chosen set nodes. For e.g. I have this starting directed graph

[image]

And I want to see relationships in subgraph of only nodes [1,2,4 and 6]. i.e. as follows:
[image]

Basically I want to show the "resulting dependencies" on just my chosen nodes.

So far, I have tried the subgraph approach as follows.

**Creating the original graph:**

```
G = nx.DiGraph() 
G.add_edges_from([(1,3),(3,4),(1,5),(5,6),(2,6),(4,6)])
```

..and then creating a **subgraph**:

```
chosen_nodes = [1,2,4,6]
SG = G.subgraph(chosen_nodes)
```

But the resulting subgraph doesn't retain any dependency relationship in edges other than the 2-6 and 4-6 relationship.

```
print(list(SG.edges))
>> [(4, 6), (2, 6)]
```

Comment: If you can determine which nodes to "ignore" in the analysis (in your case, nodes 3 and 5), you should be able to do this by contracting your nodes using `networkx.alorithms.minors.contracted_nodes`, possibly iteratively. Although it seems to me that this is at its heart more a math than a coding problem, so the math stackexchange might be helpful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one clean way to get at this is to generate a subgraph of the transitive closure.

```
from networkx.algorithms.dag import transitive_closure

def dependency_graph(G, nodes):
    return transitive_closure(G).subgraph(nodes)

print(dependency_graph(G, [1, 2, 4, 6]).edges)
>> [(1, 4), (1, 6), (4, 6), (2, 6)]
```

Comment: warning: transitive_closure would add direct edges between nodes that are simply reachable from other nodes, which in this case seems to work out as desired but in the general case would actually blow up the graph: see the correspdoning image in this section of wikipedia on the topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#In_graph_theory as well as the networkx examples here: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.transitive_closure.html